# Как правильно вывести сообщение, что ресурс занят и поток будет ждать освобождения ресурса?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Пусть есть разделяемый ресурс в программе "res". Пусть есть два потока, которые хотят зайти в критическую секцию:

```
void Meth(...){
 ... //Что нужно написать, чтобы на консоль вывелось сообщение, что тред (threadName) ждёт, когда 
synchronized (res)//Здесь разделяемый ресурс
{
//some code
}
}
```

Я реализовал вот так, всё работает (имхо) но у меня большие сомнения:

```
Class Resource {
boolean isBusy = false; //Флаг который бы переключался, если объект ресурса захватывался.
}

class A extend Thread{
String name;
static Resource res = new Resource(); //Создал объект ресурса

void Meth() throws InterruptedException {
try{
while(res.isBusy==true){
  System.out.println("Потоку " + this.name + " приходится подождать.");
  Thread.currentThread().sleep(7);
} 
synchronized (res)//Здесь разделяемый ресурс
{
res.isBusy = true; 
... //some code
res.isBusy = false; 
}
catch (Exception e){ e.printStackTrace();}
}
}
```

Нормальна ли такая реализация, если десяток потоков периодически ждёт пока освободится критическая секция, и в процессе ожидания они должны сообщить программисту, что ждут? У меня сомнения в корректности, потому что я делаю опрос занятого объекта, пытаясь прочитать его поле. Так точно можно делать, не боясь что программа вылетит?

Есть ли ещё какая-нибудь обще принятая реализация в java вывода сообщения о том, что поток не может зайти в блок синхронайзед, потому что ждёт освобождения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если прям нужно сообщать, то "критическую секцию" можно обернуть не в `synchronized`, а в

```
ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
...
while(!lock.tryLock()) { 
  print_message_and_sleep();
}

try{
  run_critical_section();
} finally {
  lock.unlock()
}
```

Но вообще, `res.isBusy = true;` -- такой подход явно не из java, поэтому если бы вопрос был более конкретным, можно было бы сделать лучше, как для читаемости-поддерживоемости кода, так и с точки зрения быстродействия. В java есть много способов и читать, и менять поле объекта вообще без блокировок.

> Есть ли ещё какая-нибудь обще принятая реализация в java вывода сообщения о том, что поток не может зайти в блок синхронайзед, потому что ждёт освобождения?

нет, потому что обычно либо так не делают (блокируют более мелкие операции, чтобы потоки друг друга не ждали); либо, если по смыслу задачи, они должны так долго ждать, тогда вероятно есть смысл переорганизовать работу с этим ресурсом (например, чтобы управляющий поток без синхронизации работал с ресурсом, и раскидывал задачи остальным потокам,а они работали параллельно без блокировки на ресурсе)

Comment: Еще лучше `tryLock` с таймаутом

Comment: да, но тогда он сначала подождет, потом сообщит, а тут по логике надо сначала сообщить, потом подождать

Comment: Как интересно).

Comment: @YuryNevinitsin Тогда уже `isLocked()` использовать. isLocked -> print -> tryLock(timeout). Конечно есть вероятность получить isLocked == false, а потом воткнуться на tryLock

Comment: @Anton, isLocked -> print -> tryLock нельзя использовать, и if-ы не помогут, т.к. здесь возникает гонка, (двое прочитали false, но лок захватил третий, то двое не сообщили, но повисли в ожидании; либо двое прочитали true, сообщили об ожидании, но один из них тут же захватил лок, и не повис)

Answer (score 1):

Для начала минусы вашего кода

1. поле `isBusy` должно быть объявлено как `volatile` иначе при чтении значения этого поля вне блока `synchronized` можно прочитать некорректное значение
2. Если вы обнаружили, что ресурс заблокирован, то усыпляете поток на некоторое время. Хотя ресурс может освободиться сейчас же
3. Существует вероятность, когда другой поток захватит ресурс после того как вы проверили флаг `isBusy`, но до входа в секцию `synchronized`

Все эти проблемы решаются заменой секции `synchronized` на объект `ReentrantLock`

```java
ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
...
// проверяем захвачен ли ресурс. Если нет, то захватываем его
if (!lock.tryLock()) {
  // Если не удалось захватить сразу, то организовываем цикл
  do {
    System.out.println("Потоку " + this.name + " приходится подождать.");
    // Пытаемся захватить блокировку сами, но уже ждем разблокировки 100 миллисекунд
  } while (!lock.tryLock(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));  // крутим цикл, пока не захватим ресурс
}

try {
  run_critical_section();
} finally {
  lock.unlock()
}
```

Comment: как интересно )

Comment: Антон спасибо. Ваш ответ очень полезен для меня, но я поставил галочку новому участнику, потому как для такого солидного участника как вы, 20 очков ничего не значат)

Comment: @AndrewKachalin Дело ведь не в очках, а в том, у кого возникнет подобная проблема и кто найдет ваш вопрос. Именно мой ответ дает на него исчерпывающий ответ, но отмечен как верный будет другой